# Pick hash algorithm based on word size

Tags: c++, c, hash

Many hashing algorithms offer different constants and implementations depending on which architecture you're trying to target.

FNV por example defines constants from 32 bits to 1024 bits.

Currently I am using the following

```
#if SIZE_MAX == ULLONG_MAX
#   define 64_BIT 1
#else
#   define 64_BIT 0
#endif
```

to detect 32 / 64 bits.

I've been reading lots of questions here on this topic and there's not seem to be a clear solution on this. Should I just pass it as a compiler flag? Isn't there a more automatic way of querying this kind of things?

How is this problem in general tackled?

Comment: Maybe `(CHAR_BIT * sizeof(void*))`? I am not so sure about that...

Comment: @Meowmere I'd put `size_t` instead of `void*` but at this point it's a matter of preference